# consulta SQL en un script PHP tarda más tiempo que en phpMyAdmin - sólo utilizo una tabla

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Agradezco que me hagan el favor de colaborarme con la siguiente inquietud, muchisimas gracias de antemano:
tengo una consulta SQL a una sóla tabla en mysql:
*Cuando se ejecuta en un script PHP a través de la web, tarda más tiempo(2.3 segundos) .
*mientras que esa misma consulta SQL en phpMyAdmin sólo toma(0.1264 segundos).

1. esta es la estructura de la tabla:

```
  CREATE TABLE catalogo_presupuesto (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  Grupo varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Subg varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Cta_Prog varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Subc_Subp varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Objg_Proy varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Ord1_Spry1 varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Ord2_Spry2 varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Ord2_Spry3 varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Ord2_Spry4 varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  Ord2_Spry5 varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  clasificador_dnp varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  clasificador_dane varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  largo int(11) NOT NULL,
  rubro_presupuestal varchar(75) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  concepto varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  concepto1 varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  nivel int(11) NOT NULL,
  tipo varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  costo_total double(24,2) NOT NULL,
  tr varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  valor double(24,2) NOT NULL,
  entidad varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  seccion varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  vigencia varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  tipo2 varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  desde date NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01',
  hasta date NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-12-31',
  tipo_entidad varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  clasificador_sector varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  clasificador_programa varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  clasificador_elemento_constitutivo varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  clasificador_producto varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  clasificador_fuente_financiacion varchar(75) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  clasificador_economico varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  clasificador_cuin varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  clasificador_1 varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  clasificador_2 varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  bpin varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  ssf varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  original char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S',
  usuario varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='catalogo CCPET';

ALTER TABLE catalogo_presupuesto
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY rubro_presupuestal (rubro_presupuestal,tr,entidad,seccion,vigencia,tipo2),
  ADD KEY rubro_presupuestal_2 (rubro_presupuestal,tr,entidad,seccion,vigencia,tipo2),
  ADD KEY clasificador_dnp (clasificador_dnp),
  ADD KEY clasificador_dane (clasificador_dane),
  ADD KEY clasificador_fuente_financiacion (clasificador_fuente_financiacion),
  ADD KEY llave_consulta (entidad(10),seccion(5),vigencia(4),tipo2);
```

2. esta es la consulta SQL:

```
select 
Grupo, Subg, Cta_Prog, Subc_Subp, Objg_Proy, Ord1_Spry1, Ord2_Spry2, Ord2_Spry3, Ord2_Spry4, Ord2_Spry5, 
           clasificador_dnp, clasificador_dane,  largo, rubro_presupuestal, concepto, concepto1,  nivel, tipo, costo_total, tr, 
           
   (select if (  w.tipo_entidad='A', COALESCE(sum(valor),''), if (w.tr<>'',   COALESCE(w.valor,''),''   )  )  from catalogo_presupuesto p 
 where p.vigencia=w.vigencia and p.rubro_presupuestal 
  like concat(w.rubro_presupuestal,'%') and 
  p.tr like '1101%'  and p.seccion like '0400%'  and p.entidad='1234567890') as valor,
           
entidad, seccion, vigencia, tipo2, desde, hasta, id, tipo_entidad, clasificador_sector, clasificador_programa, clasificador_elemento_constitutivo, clasificador_producto, 
clasificador_fuente_financiacion, clasificador_economico, clasificador_cuin,  clasificador_1, clasificador_2, bpin, ssf, original, usuario

FROM catalogo_presupuesto as w where ( w.tipo_entidad='C' or w.tipo_entidad='D' or tipo_entidad='A') and w.vigencia='2021' and  w.tipo2='Gastos' and 
w.seccion like '0400%' and w.entidad='1234567890'   
and (w.tr='1101'  or w.tr='')                           
order by w.rubro_presupuestal, w.valor desc
```

mi inquietud final es: por que en phpMyAdmin tarda menos de medio segundo, mientras que al ejecutarlo desde el navegador web y al revisar por(inspeccionar elemento) observo que el script tarda mas de dos segundos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! tus procesos se ejecutan en lugares diferentes.. esa diferencia es logica